# PDF Security

Tags: security, pdf

I have a question about PDF security preferences. Can I change an editable pdf to readable pdf programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - with for example [PDFStamp](http://www.verypdf.com/pdfstamp/) on Windows ([Command line reference](http://www.verypdf.com/pdfstamp/pdfstamp_cmd/pdfstamp_manual_cmd.htm))

Answer (score 1):

My Perl CAM::PDF library has a command-line utility called [rewritepdf.pl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/bin/rewritepdf.pl) that can do this quite easily with the `-P` flag.  The library exposes this functionality quite easily, too.

Comment: decrypting open password works, but decrypting permission password (content copying, etc) not working? ... any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adding security to a PDF which stops people from being able to edit it, is quite easy using a variety of different PDF toolkits (iText, PDFSharp, Quick PDF Library, etc).

Answer (score 1):

PDF encryption may not be honored in some tools.

You can use tools such as [PDFLEO](http://www.rockpdf.com) to encrypt PDF documents ([command line reference](http://mdn.morovia.com/manuals/pdfleo-1/PDF-Overview.php#N101BB))